# How do I reduce mouse sensitivity in Seven Kingdoms: Ancient Adversaries (7KAA)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, seven-kingdoms-ancient-adversaries

On Ubuntu, the mouse sensitivity in *Seven Kingdoms: Ancient Adversaries* (7KAA) is so high that I have great difficulty in pressing the menu buttons. How can I reduce the mouse sensitivity in 7KAA? 7KAA is the only application on my computer with mouse sensitivity problems.